# Is there a way to identify which pointer is dragged in google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have a google map with multiple pointers associated with address fields (see attached image). What I need is when any pointer dragged the address field associated to that pointer should update with new address.

However, I have calculated address after pointer dragged but I am having some hard time to specify which pointer is dragged (either A,B,C or D) so that I can update address field associated to that pointer, can anyone please help how to get the updated pointer info if we have multiple pointers how can we identify which pointer is dragged?

Using diraction_changed event

```
directionsDisplay.addListener('directions_changed', function() {
          computeTotalDistance(directionsDisplay.getDirections());
        });
```

Here is the complete working example at JSFiddle
[https://jsfiddle.net/kamrankhatti/g83mjg4o](https://jsfiddle.net/kamrankhatti/g83mjg4o/)

Thanks in advance.

[image: Google Map Pointers]

Answer (score 3):

Add some `id` to Marker:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {
        lat: bounds.south + latSpan * Math.random(),
        lng: bounds.west + lngSpan * Math.random()
      },
      map: map,
      customId: "MarkerA",
    });
```

And then read `id` inside `dragend` event listener:

```
 marker.addListener('dragend', function() {
    console.log(marker['customId']);
  });
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4mtyu/1923/

Comment: We are using pointers not markers. JSFiddle [https://jsfiddle.net/kamrankhatti/g83mjg4o/](https://jsfiddle.net/kamrankhatti/g83mjg4o/)